# "Komisch" in der bedeutung von "lustig"

Tags: word-usage

Meiner Erfahrung nach hört und auch liest man das Wort "komisch" meist in der Bedeutung von "seltsam" und mehr selten in der Bedeutung von "lustig". Insbesondere geben Wörterbücher nur die erste Bedeutung an, wenn das Wort predikativ verwendet wird, also mit "sein". Weiter geben Wörterbücher an, dass diese Bedeutung umgangssprachlich sei, und (nur?) in der gesprochenen Sprache vorkommt.

Ich habe dieses Beispiel gefunden, das mir komisch (sic!) vorkommt: [Oberinspektor Marek](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4QFERp0xTuQ) Das Beispiel ist alt und regional und vielleicht nicht allgemeingültig. Bei 44:55 hört man deutlich:

> Ihre Situation ist nicht so komisch

also "komisch" in predikativer Stellung, wobei die Bedeutung eindeutig "lustig" oder "zum Lachen" gemeint wird, und auch sofort in dieser Bedeutung vom Angesprochenen aufgefasst wird.

Meine Frage: Ist die Verwendung im Beispiel ungewöhnlich, veraltet oder regional, oder ist sie gar als ganz normaler Sprachgebrauch aufzufassen?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Du fragst zur Hochphase des Gegenbeispiels:
Im Moment ist in vielen Regionen Deutschlands der Karneval in vollem Gang und sehr viele Reden, Darbietungen, Motivwagen, Verkleidungen, ... sind eindeutig *komisch* im Sinne von *lustig* und auch genau so gemeint.  Auch in prädikativer Verwendung wie in der Frage. (Dass manche davon auch besonders für Karnevalsmuffel *seltsam* oder *wunderlich* sein können, tut nichts zur Sache.)

Fazit: Beide Verwendungen sind möglich und die Bedeutung erschließt sich aus dem Kontext.

Eine Ausnahme sollte allerdings erwähnt werden:
Wenn jemandem *etwas komisch vorkommt* ist damit immer etwas *Seltsames*, im Sinne von *nicht so, wie es sein sollte* und im weitesten Sinne *möglicherweise gefährlich*.

Comment: "die Bedeutung erschließt sich aus dem Kontext" - als Muttersprachler finde ich, dass sie das leider mitunter gar nicht tut. Deshalb achte ich darauf, nach Möglichkeit nur "lustig" oder "seltsam" zu verwenden.

Comment: @O.R.Mapper da sind wir auf einer Wellenlänge. Besonders bei meinen Kindern achte ich sehr darauf, dass sie sich eindeutig ausdrücken. Leider wird OP nicht die Gelegenheit haben, andere *Sprecher* auf dieselbe Präzision zu trainieren, da bleibt also nur der Kontext für das *Verständnis*.